# Which is faster ..passing variables to a javascript function or running a MySql query to fetch the values?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I wish to know the following: Which one of the following is faster- passing variables to a javascript function and then passing it on to a php file to carry out some operation or running a MySql query to fetch the variables in the php file without passing them? ..Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to measure. There are too many factors that play a role here.

Comment: run a benchmark

Comment: @Fred-ii- What's a benchmark?..Sorry I'm very new to this..thanks!

Comment: Without code for context this is like asking if a car is faster than a truck. It really depends on the characteristics of both vehicles, or in this case, the methods used and what "faster" means specifically. Lower latency? Less load on your system? You're speaking in abstract terms about something that has to be measured very specifically.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)

Comment: Ohkay..thanks a lot!

Comment: welcome. However, you're dealing with mysql. If your database isn't properly indexed, then using js won't help speed it up any. @eagleAtlantis

Comment: Oh okay...thanks a lot, @Fred-ii- !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pretty similar request  .. if the related value are already available to te client and  you need this to some other page then tecnically 
the javascript ajax request involve only the internet transfer of the call and the transfer of the result  .. the use of database access in addition to sending the request and receiving data also implies  the access  to the database so normally should be more fast ths ajax  method

Comment: So normally the ajax method is faster?

Comment: @eagleAtlantis  if you have already the value  the ajax method don't require an adding (unuseful) database access ..

Comment: Oh okay! I get it now! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific reason for using Javascript, for instance, updating displayed records without reloading the page, use PHP directly. You can always run the php function in a class on a separate file if you wish to keep your html and php separate.

My personal experience of ajax, which you should remember still has to access PHP in order to execute server-side requests, is that it *can appear* slow. Whether or not it actually is slower, it leaves the page in place whilst executing the code and so might present that illusion to the user.

Also, I think the simplest solution is the best, so if you don't need ajax you shouldn't use it, but if you do need it then there is no reason not to do so that I am aware of.

Comment: Ohkay..thanks a lot!! Made me rethink my way of coding!